# How to connect a separate assembler procedure to a C++ project using Dev-C++

Tags: c++, assembly, dev-c++

My task is to connect a separate assembler procedure to the c++ code. I use Dev-C++ for writing.

There is an example of a task that doesn't work for me.

```
//file1.cpp
#include <iostream>
extern "C" int MAS_FUNC (int *, int);
int main()
{
    int *mas,n,k;
    n=5;
    mas=new int[n];
    for (int i=0; i < n; i=i+1)
    {
        mas[i]=i;
    }
    k = MAS_FUNC(mas,n);
}
```

```
;file2.asm
.586
.MODEL FLAT, C
.CODE
MAS_FUNC PROC C mas:dword, n:dword
mov esi,mas
mov eax, [esi+4]
shl eax, 1
```

type here

```
ret
MAS_FUNC ENDP
END
```

I don't really understand how everything should work, but I just put .cpp and .asm in the same folder. (And this is probably wrong, because in VS it seems like you need to connect some kind of masm, etc.) At startup.cpp throws this error **...undefined reference to `MAS_FUNC**. I didn't find any guides on Dev-C++, so I'm writing here how to make it work.

Comment: How are you compiling and linking?

Comment: Just like you need a C++ compiler to compile C++ source code; you need an assembler to compile assembly source code.  Have you got both of these tools?  Dev-C++ is an IDE which may or may not ship with a compiler and/or assembler.  What platform (Windows, Linux etc) are you targeting?

Comment: If you haven't assembled your assembly file and linked it with your compiled C++ source file, you can expect exactly this type of error.

Comment: @RichardCritten my compiler is tdm-gcc 9.2 64-bit. I hope this is what was meant. I work in Windows.  I know how to do assembler inserts in c++, they work for me. But my task, roughly speaking, is to run .asm through .cpp, as I understand

Comment: @Chris you mean files .obj and .exe from .asm? I work with ordinary assembler programs in dosbox. Unfortunately, I can't convert file2.asm to .obj and .exe using tasm and tlink